# Putting array of collection inside another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections inside my database.
One is **Order** and another is **product**

Now structure for order is like this:

```
   { 
    order_id:12333,
    ......
    items: [
    {
    product_id:4555,
    product_quantity:1
    ..},{
    ...
    }
    ]
    }
```

Structure for product is :

```
{
 product_id:4555,
 product_quantity:1
 ..
}
```

for this should I create any reference for product collection inside order collection or simply adding data inside order collection is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference your product only by the id in the Order collection (I am not sure even about the **quantity** field, but ok). The main point of not-relational databases (NoSQL) is to make things simpler, so only an id reference could be enough.

If by any reason, you need to retrieve the product information in a query for order, as from Mongodb 3.2, you can use the `$lookup` function when performing an `$aggregation`.

Here is the reference of how to use it:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Hope my answer was helpful.